# C# - Facebook API used with desktop apps?

Tags: c#, facebook, api, chat

Can I use the facebook API to make a windows desktop application? Like create a chat client to use to chat with facebook users??

Answer (score 1):

yes, while I have not done it myself, there seem to be standalone apps developed for facebook like [FaceoffIM](http://www.faceoffim.com/)... so I am assuming you can.

If I remember correctly, Telerik is maintaining something in Silverlight called [fdek](http://www.telerik.com/products/fdeck.aspx)... which would again mean in principle it is possible.

There is also a [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) available on Codeplex which might be of use... under its project description it states "The Facebook C# SDK helps .Net developers build web, desktop, Silverlight, and Windows Phone 7 applications that integrate with Facebook."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop desktop applications that interact with the Facebook API's.

You can use the C# SDK which is introduced in this official blog post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395

Basically, any desktop application just needs to send http web requests to the Facebook API's. The easiest would be to use the the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Hope this helps.